# How to use "create table as" with dates that is aggregated through group by in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, create-table, database-partitioning

Given a data that looks as follows where the date is in string format `YYYYMMDD`:

| item | vietnamese | cost | unique_id | sales_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fruits | trai cay | 10 | abc123 | 20211001 |
| fruits | trai cay | 8 | foo99 | 20211001 |
| fruits | trai cay | 9 | foo99 | 20211001 |
| vege | rau | 3 | rr1239 | 20211001 |
| vege | rau | 3 | rr1239 | 20211001 |
| fruits | trai cay | 12 | abc123 | 20211002 |
| fruits | trai cay | 14 | abc123 | 20211002 |
| fruits | trai cay | 8 | abc123 | 20211002 |
| fruits | trai cay | 5 | foo99 | 20211002 |
| vege | rau | 8 | rr1239 | 20211002 |
| vege | rau | 1 | rr1239 | 20211002 |
| vege | rau | 12 | ud9213 | 20211002 |
| vege | rau | 19 | r11759 | 20211002 |
| fruits | trai cay | 6 | foo99 | 20211003 |
| fruits | trai cay | 2 | abc123 | 20211003 |
| fruits | trai cay | 12 | abc123 | 20211003 |
| vege | rau | 1 | ud97863 | 20211003 |
| vege | rau | 9 | r112359 | 20211003 |
| fruits | trai cay | 6 | foo99 | 20211004 |
| fruits | trai cay | 2 | abc123 | 20211004 |
| fruits | trai cay | 12 | abc123 | 20211004 |
| vege | rau | 9 | r112359 | 20211004 |

The goal is

- select a max of N rows per `sales_date` for specific time frame
- aggregate the data by using `group by` on the item column,

e.g. for max of 3 rows per day between '20211002' and '20211004':

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT item, 
            max(vietnamese) as vietnamese,
            sum(cost) as total_cost,
            array_agg(cost) as costs,
            array_agg(unique_id) as unique_ids,
            row_number() over (partition by max(sales_date) order by rand()) as row
     FROM mytable
     where sales_date between '20211002' and '20211004'
  GROUP BY item)
where row <= 3
limit 9
```

**Note:** `vietnamese` column per `item` is a one-to-one mapping thus the `max(vietnamese)`

The results from the above should look something like:

| item | vietnamese | costs | unique_ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fruits | trai cay | [8] | [abc123] |
| vege | rau | [8, 1] | [rr1239, rr1239] |
| fruits | trai cay | [2, 12] | [abc123, abc123] |
| vege | rau | [1] | [ud97863] |
| fruits | trai cay | [6, 2, 12] | [foo99, abc123, abc123] |

The desired output is and saved as `parquet` format:

| item | vietnamese | costs | unique_ids | sales_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| fruits | trai cay | [8] | [abc123] | 20211002 |
| vege | rau | [8, 1] | [rr1239, rr1239] | 20211002 |
| fruits | trai cay | [2, 12] | [abc123, abc123] | 20211003 |
| vege | rau | [1] | [ud97863] | 20211003 |
| fruits | trai cay | [6, 2, 12] | [foo99, abc123, abc123] | 20211004 |

And the aim is to save it to `s3://somes3path/`, with some structure in the directory:

```
s3://somes3path/
     item=fruits/
        sales_date=20211002
        sales_date=20211003
     item=vege/
        sales_date=20211002
        sales_date=20211003
        sales_date=20211004
```

**How do I achieve that expected output in the directory structure as listed abvoe?**

---

I've tried this but it's not saving it in the right directory structure as I expected:

```
CREATE TABLE somedb.mytable
WITH ( format = 'PARQUET', external_location = 's3://somes3path/', 
       partitioned_by = ARRAY['item'], 
       bucketed_by = ARRAY['sales_date'], bucket_count = 30) AS 
SELECT *
FROM 
    (SELECT item, 
            max(vietnamese) as vietnamese,
            sum(cost) as total_cost,
            array_agg(cost) as costs,
            array_agg(unique_id) as unique_ids,
            first(sales_date) as sales_date,
            row_number() over (partition by max(sales_date) order by rand()) as row
     FROM mytable
     where sales_date between '20211002' and '20211004'
  GROUP BY item)
where row <= 3
limit 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output is only partitioned by `item`, if you change it to be partitioned by `item` and `sales_date` you will get the desired directory structure. Remove the bucketing as it won't have any effect when you partition on `sales_date`:

```
WITH (
  format = 'PARQUET',
  external_location = 's3://somes3path/', 
  partitioned_by = ARRAY['item', 'sales_date']
)
```